# What does 好 mean in this context?

Tags: grammar

In the following phrase, what does 好 mean in this context?

[Traditional](https://www.jw.org/cmn-hant/%E5%87%BA%E7%89%88%E7%89%A9/%E6%9B%B8%E7%B1%8D/%E8%81%96%E7%B6%93%E7%9C%9F%E7%90%86/%E8%B4%96%E5%83%B9%E4%B8%8A%E5%B8%9D%E6%9C%80%E5%AF%B6%E8%B2%B4%E7%9A%84%E7%A6%AE%E7%89%A9/):

> 我們​人人​天生​都​不完美，每​逢​想​做​對​的​事，內心​往往​要​經歷​好​一​番​掙扎，而且​都​會​說​錯​話​做​錯​事

[Simplified](https://www.jw.org/cmn-hans/%E5%87%BA%E7%89%88%E7%89%A9/%E4%B9%A6%E7%B1%8D/%E5%9C%A3%E7%BB%8F%E7%9C%9F%E7%90%86/%E8%B5%8E%E4%BB%B7%E4%B8%8A%E5%B8%9D%E6%9C%80%E5%AE%9D%E8%B4%B5%E7%9A%84%E7%A4%BC%E7%89%A9/):

> 我们​人人​天生​都​不完美，每​逢​想​做​对​的​事，内心​往往​要​经历​好​一​番​挣扎，而且​都​会​说​错​话​做​错事

Comment: [好](https://www.moedict.tw/好)
副詞 (adv.)
7. 置於數量詞或時間詞之前，表示多(many/much/a lot)或久(long/lasting)的意思。

Answer (score 2):

The correct word boundary should be 好​一​番, which means a lot of. In your sentence, "we have to go through a lot of struggles."

Answer (score 2):

'好' means 'quite' in ‘好一番’.
'好' is adverb here.

Answer (score 0):

经历​好：V＋好，好 functions as complement of result 结果补语 cf.http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_5f9ec9b00100i4jg.html 
3、动词+好:晚饭做好了没有？我要写好毛笔字。这件事情我已经想好了。我们说好了一起回家。

Yufa! A Practical Guide to Mandarin Chinese Grammar， 
verbs associated with 好 meaning "properly" or "securely" are 学、做、放、带、拿、准备，etc.e.g.各位旅客请在座位上坐好，并且系好安全带，飞机就要起飞了。大家都准备好了吗？可以出发了吧？
When 好 indicates completion of a task,an assignment,piece of work it shares similarities with 完，therefore they sometimes are interchangeable. However 好 tends to mean the completed work can be shown, whereas 完 indicates that once sth. is done it's gone.: verbs associated with this meaning are 作、写、画、洗、翻译，etc.e.g.王老师花了三年，才把那语法书写好。Compare 今天的功课真多，我写了三个多小时，还没写完。

here  挣扎 desperate struggle， ​番​ classifier for the frequency or number of times an action or
deed is carried out - mostly used in idiomatic phrases, 好一番挣扎 numeral measure word combination 
数词和量词 e.g. 费了好一番力气 I wasted a lot of effort, therefore 经历好一番挣扎 can mean "lived through/experienced/went through a good deal of desperate struggle"